# author slug in the backend

Tags: author, slug

hi and thanks for reading
i try to grab the authors slug in the backend.

```
get_the_author_meta( 'user_nicename' );
```

is empty.
i tried to google this issue, but cant find any concrete info on how to handle the backend. any hints would be nice. i keep writing to meet the quality standards. sorry for spaming but this seems to be the only solution. call it spam, i call it anyoing, but i wont complain, cause otherwise, what stupid text would end up here, just to get a little help.

Answer (score 1):

Please [read the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author_meta) on this function. Outside of the loop, your second arg must be a user ID. Inside the loop, WP grabs it from the post data.

```
get_the_author_meta('user_nicename', $userID);
```

Comment: ok. got it, thank you. was confused cause it worked in some other place (well, in the loop).

Answer (score 1):

to get, what i wanted, not just in the loop, but also in the backend, i wrote

```
function my_function( $id = 0 ) {
    $post = &get_post($id);
    $author = get_userdata($post->post_author);
    $user_url = $author->user_nicename;
}
```